# Report generation in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How can I generate a consolidated summary report for multiple threads under a single test plan in JMeter.
We are able to fetch report individually for each thread group.Is there any chance that we can get consolidated report for all thread groups under single test plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the report from i.e. [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener just remove all Summary Report listeners from all Thread Groups and add one at the same level as the Thread Groups

[image: JMeter Listener for All Thread Groups]

The concept is known as [Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), i.e.:

- If you add a listener as a child of a [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - it will be applied to this sampler only
- If you add a listener as a child of a [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - it will be applied to all Samplers in the Thread Groups
- If you add a listener as a child of the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) - it will be applied to all samplers in the Test Plan

---

Also be aware that starting from JMeter 3.0 there is a possibility to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)